# Next.js i18n static generation also adds defaultLocale as subpath

Tags: javascript, next.js

We are trying to add locales using SSG according to the docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#dynamic-routes-and-getstaticprops-pages

Our config is:

```
i18n: {
    locales: ['sv', 'en'],
    defaultLocale: 'sv',
  },
```

According to the docs, the `defaultLocale` should be rendered at the root. So when we return the path like this (according to the docs):

```
export const getStaticPaths = ({ locales }) => {
  return {
    paths: [
      // if no `locale` is provided only the defaultLocale will be generated
      { params: { slug: 'foo' } },
    ],
    fallback: true,
  }
}
```

It will build a `/blog/foo` in Swedish. However, when we visit `/sv/blog/foo` (after build & start) it will show the same page, and it also says so in the build summary:

```
├ ● /blog/[slug] (367292 ms)                            1.33 kB         372 kB
├   ├ /sv/blog/foo (12555 ms)
```

It seems odd that next generates duplicate pages for static sites with dynamic routes, and I can’t find anything that explains this. Does anyone know if this is a feature or bug?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the issue is. `/blog/foo` and `/sv/blog/foo` are the same page (since `sv` is the default locale), it'll only build it once. The default locale page can always be accessed with or without the prefix.

Comment: in case you want to do client side i18n redirect: https://dev.to/adrai/static-html-export-with-i18n-compatibility-in-nextjs-8cd